# How to read Json response into Document object of Document AI in C#

Tags: c#, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud-document-ai

I am trying to read json file from cloud storage and trying to convert that into Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1.Document.

I have done POC, but its throwing exception `Google.Protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: 'Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.'`

First I am reading .Json file into MemoryStream and trying to Merge in to Document.

```
  using Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1;

  public static void StreamToDocument()
    {
        byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\upload\\temp.json");
        
        using (Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileContents))
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            var byteArray = memoryStream;
            doc.MergeFrom(byteArray);
        }           
    }
```

Error Message I am getting is

[image]

Is there any other way I can achieve this ?

Comment: Does your JSON file follow this structure? https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document

Comment: yes, json structure as per Document type. This Json is DocumentAI output json.

Comment: Can you provide a sample JSON that could reproduce the issue? Just so the community can easily test this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that you've specified there expects the data to be *binary* protobuf content. For JSON, you want:

```cs
string json = File.ReadAllText("C:\\upload\\temp.json");
Document document = Document.Parser.ParseJson(json);
```

Comment: we have done it something like this.



var txtOut = File.ReadAllText(rawJson);
JsonParser.Settings settings = new JsonParser.Settings(10);
Google.Protobuf.JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(settings);
var d1 = parser.Parse<Document>(txtOut);

Comment: @tt0206: Yes, that'll be fine too (although I wouldn't expect the default recursion limit of 100 to actually cause a problem).