# Convert ProcessResponse to json and then back to a ProcessResponse object again

Tags: c#, cloud-document-ai

I'm working on a document AI implementation where we are sending multiple related requests gathering the responses and re-combining them.  This is all done in C#. As part of this I need to convert a ProcessResponse to a json string and then downstream convert it back to a ProcessResponse object.  What is the best way to do this?

I was looking at using JsonFormatter to create the json string but I can't find a way to convert it back to a ProcessResponse.  From what I'm reading this seems like a common problem encountered with all Proto Buffer related objects.

Comment: I believe I have figured it out based on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72091900/how-to-read-json-response-into-document-object-of-document-ai-in-c-sharp?rq=2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked answer in the comments is an option.

[How to read Json response into Document object of Document AI in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72091900/how-to-read-json-response-into-document-object-of-document-ai-in-c-sharp?rq=2)

```cs
string json = File.ReadAllText("C:\\upload\\temp.json");
Document document = Document.Parser.ParseJson(json);
```

---

This is not entirely related, but could be useful. For Python, there is the [Document AI Toolbox](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/toolbox) which creates an interface around the Document object to make it easier to handle. (Including consolidating the Document shards from Batch Processing.) You can look at the [open source library code](https://github.com/googleapis/python-documentai-toolbox) to get a sense of how to handle this and make your own in C#.